# I need to write a parser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a novice programmer. I need to output all the URLs of the site with `BeautifulSoup` and `requests`. Link to the website : https://www.dns-shop.ru/

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi there. Please add some more details, such as the error message, the commands you are using, maybe the full script content.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**BeautifulSoup** can only parse server-rendering websites that return full of HTML or XML strings but "https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/" is a client-rendering website, it needs a browser compline JS script to render HTML or XML strings thus BeautifulSoup can't parse this URL.

**response.text** is not your expected HTML string as you inspect in the browser, you can view the real HTML string that was returned by entering "view-source:[https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/"](https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/%22) in the browser(Chrome) address bar.

You should read the article to do it: https://weikunye1225.medium.com/web-crawling-with-beautifulsoup-advance-42c14147050b

Comment: It's not right to say BeautifulSoup can only parse SSR website---in fact, the article you suggested basically use selenium to render the HTML and handed that piece of HTML to be parsed by selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass headers as well to your request. As the website has restrictions on requests due to CORS.

Following code worked for me

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/"
headers = {
    'Host': 'www.dns-shop.ru', 
    'Origin': 'https://www.dns-shop.ru/', 
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```